# ¿Cómo pintar una fila de un dataframe si una celda cumple una determinada condición?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, style

estoy trabajando con Python 3.8 y quiero sacar un excel a partir de unas tablas. Tengo la siguiente función que pinta una fila entera de un excel:

```
def highlight_row_content(column, value1, color1):
    cont_val = column == value1
    color = color1
    return ['background-color:' + color if cont_val.any() else '' for v in cont_val]
```

Pero la función pinta la fila si el valor de la celda es igual al que le paso como parámetro; y lo que necesito es que si la celda **contiene** el valor que le paso como parámetro, aunque tenga más texto, pinte la fila igualmente.

Es decir, si la celda contiene "Fallo (13/04/2020)", si yo le paso como parámetro "Fallo" quiero que se pinte toda la fila, pero ahora mismo, con la función tal cual está arriba, no lo pinta

¿Alguna idea para hacerlo? Muchas gracias

Comment: "si la celda contiene el valor que le paso como parámetro" es algo ambiguo en ciertas situaciones, me explico: si tu columna es de tipo `str`, si contiene `"saludando a todo el que veo"` debe pintarse si se pasa `"salud"` como `value1` o solo si se pasa `"saludando"`. No se si se puede dar, pero la implementación sería muy distinta.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con lo siguiente: si la celda contiene "Fallo (13/04/2020)", si yo le paso como parámetro "Fallo" quiero que se pinte toda la fila, pero ahora mismo, con la función tal cual está arriba, no lo pinta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es seleccionar aquellas en las que una celda tenga una determinada subcadena, debes usar lo que vendía a ser el operador de pertenencia `in` en Python estándar, que en Pandas de forma vectorizada para `Series` de tipo `str` sería [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
import pandas as pd


def highlight_row_content(column, value, color):
    cont_val = column.str.contains(value, case=False)
    return [f'background-color: {color}' if cont_val.any() else '' for v in cont_val]

tabla = pd.DataFrame({"Evento": ("Fallo (10/04/2020)",
                                 "fallon (11/04/2020)",
                                 "fallo (12/04/2020)",
                                 "Reinicio (13/04/2020)")}
                      )


style_table = tabla.style.apply(
    highlight_row_content, value="Fallo", color='red', axis=1
    )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además está "vitaminado" puedes usar expresiones regulares para búsquedas más complejas. Por ejemplo, si quieres buscar una palabra (que no solo una subcadena) puedes hacer:

```
import re
import pandas as pd


def highlight_row_content(column, value, color):
    cont_val = column.str.contains(f"\\b{value}\\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return [f'background-color: {color}' if cont_val.any() else '' for v in cont_val]

tabla = pd.DataFrame({"Evento": ("Fallo (10/04/2020)",
                                 "fallon (11/04/2020)",
                                 "fallo (12/04/2020)",
                                 "Reinicio (13/04/2020)")}
                      )


style_table = tabla.style.apply(
    highlight_row_content, value="Fallo", color='red', axis=1
    )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Enorme esta aportación. Te debo una.